# CodeIgniter Does Not Require a Template Engine

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, cakephp-1.3, codeigniter-2

Please explain what a template engine is, and what it is used for. What are the paragraphs below trying to say? I don't follow the author's explanation.

> Although CodeIgniter does come with a simple template parser that can
>   be optionally used, it does not force you to use one. Template engines
>   simply can not match the performance of native PHP, and the syntax
>   that must be learned to use a template engine is usually only
>   marginally easier than learning the basics of PHP. Consider this block
>   of PHP code:
>
> ```
> <ul>
>
> <?php foreach ($addressbook as $name):?>
>
> <li><?=$name?></li>
>
> <?php endforeach; ?>
>
> </ul>
> ```
>
> Contrast this with the pseudo-code used by a template engine:
>
> ```
> <ul>
>
> {foreach from=$addressbook item="name"}
>
> <li>{$name}</li>
>
> {/foreach}
>
> </ul>
> ```
>
> Yes, the template engine example is a bit cleaner, but it comes at the
>   price of performance, as the pseudo-code must be converted back into
>   PHP to run. Since one of our goals is maximum performance, we opted to
>   not require the use of a template engine.

Comment: What is who trying to explain to you? You're obviously quoting something. Tell us what.

Comment: a few people says that template engines are easier to work with for designers who doesn't understand programming well, but this is not the case anymore so basically in php it's a waste of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A template engine is simply a way to embed your back-end code into your html. This is more common in languages like Python and Ruby than PHP since PHP already supports embedding within html code.

That specific templating engine may be easier for those coming from other back-end languages, particularly Python or Ruby since Django and Rails have very similar-looking syntax for templates.

While not necessarily a "template engine", I typically organize my Codeigniter projects where I have a template.php view that contains the skeleton layout and the content of each page of the site/application is a separate view that is loaded within the template.php file. This way I am not rewriting code on each page.

Template engines are all about personal preference--they aren't needed, but some people feel more comfortable using them if that's what they are used to. And people are more effective the less they have to think about their workflow!

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter Userguide describe that CodeIgniter does come with a simple template parser that can be optionally used, it does not force you to use one.

But if u want to use template, I suggest to use this library that it is very simple.

http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html